# SparkSQL - Lag function?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I see in this [DataBricks post](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html), there is support for window functions in SparkSql, in particular I'm trying to use the lag() window function.

I have rows of credit card transactions, and I've sorted them, now I want to iterate over the rows, and for each row display the amount of the transaction, and the difference of the current row's amount and the preceding row's amount.

Following the DataBricks post, I've come up with this query, but it's throwing an exception at me and I can't quite undestand why..

This is in PySpark.. tx is my dataframe already created at registered as a temp table.

```
test =sqlContext.sql("SELECT tx.cc_num,tx.trans_date,tx.trans_time,tx.amt, (lag(tx.amt) OVER (PARTITION BY tx.cc_num ORDER BY  tx.trans_date,tx.trans_time ROW BETWEEN PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as prev_amt from tx")
```

and the exception (truncated)..

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o76.sql.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.67] failure: ``)'' expected but identifier OVER found
```

I'd really apprecaite any insight, this functionality is rather new and there's not a lot to go on as far as existing examples or other related posts.

**Edit**

I've also attempted to do this without SQL statement as below, but continue to get an error. I've used this with Hive and SQLContext, and receive the same error.

```
windowSpec = \
Window \
    .partitionBy(h_tx_df_ordered['cc_num']) \
    .orderBy(h_tx_df_ordered['cc_num'],h_tx_df_ordered['trans_date'],h_tx_df_ordered['trans_time'])

windowSpec.rowsBetween(-1, 0)

lag_amt = \
   (lag(h_tx_df_ordered['amt']).over(windowSpec) - h_tx_df_ordered['amt'])
    tx_df_ordered.select(
    h_tx_df_ordered['cc_num'],
    h_tx_df_ordered['trans_date'],
    h_tx_df_ordered['trans_time'],
    h_tx_df_ordered['amt'],
    lag_amt.alias("prev_amt")).show()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rdd_raw_data.py", line 116, in <module>
    lag_amt.alias("prev_amt")).show()
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 721, in select
    jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))
  File "/home/brandon/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/brandon/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o152.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Could not resolve window function 'lag'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:38)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Frame specification should start with a keyword `ROWS` not `ROW`
2. Frame specification requires either lower bound value

   ```
   ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
   ```

   or `UNBOUNDED` keyword

   ```
   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
   ```
3. `LAG` function doesn't accept frame at all so a correct SQL query with lag can look like this

   ```
   SELECT tx.cc_num,tx.trans_date,tx.trans_time,tx.amt, LAG(tx.amt) OVER (
        PARTITION BY tx.cc_num ORDER BY  tx.trans_date,tx.trans_time
   ) as prev_amt from tx
   ```

**Edit**:

Regarding SQL DSL usage:

1. As you can read in an error message

   > Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContex

   Be sure to initialize `sqlContext` using `HiveContext` not `SQLContext`
2. `windowSpec.rowsBetween(-1, 0)` does nothing, but once again frame specification is not supported by the `lag` function.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've updated the post with additional, non-sql syntax (new error), as well as attempting to update the SQL syntax per your suggestions (same error). Perhaps you could review my second try and the SQL syntax and specifically locate what I've done wrong? 

`test =sqlContext.sql("SELECT tx.cc_num,tx.trans_date,tx.trans_time,tx.amt, (lag() OVER (PARTITION BY tx.cc_num ORDER BY  tx.trans_date,tx.trans_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) from tx")`