# Declaring HiveContext in Spark shows an error

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have copy pasted the code from Apache Spark official Website. But my Eclipse shows an error!
Link:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Screen shot of the code[image]

It shows the **"The field JavaSparkContext.sc is not visible"**
and it suggest some quick fix by making **sc.sc to sc.sc()**.But  after that I can't use it like SQLContext(like querying and all).

My need is described in following sentences.I need to run a query in Spark SQL as describe in the link given in next sentence. But it always shows an error message described in the question.
[SparkSQL - Lag function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568854/sparksql-lag-function).
According to the accepted answer I tried some fixes (make it to HiveContext). But it gives the above problem.